# Transfer images from ArangoDB’s file system to amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, arangodb

I am currently using ArangoDB to store all the data I'm using for my application, including images. Now I want to migrate to S3 to store the image files and transfer the files I currently have in my ArangoDB.

I am aware that images are stored in file system, but I am not sure how to actually transfer them to s3.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The location of the data files is implementation-specific, as it can be changed at install and startup.  On Linux, the default directory is `/var/lib/arangodb3`.

But in my experience, backing-up the raw storage files is ***not*** a good idea.  I have found it very difficult to restore or access data with this method.  Instead, I recommend using one of these two "official" methods:

1. [Hot backups](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/backup-restore.html#hot-backups) (enterprise-edition only)
2. JSON export (using [arangobackup](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangobackup.html)/[arangoimport](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangoimport.html))

Snapshot-style "Hot backups" are really great - truly the preferred method.  They have everything you would need (speed, reliability, portability, etc.), with only a few case-dependent [limitations](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.7/programs-arangobackup-limitations.html).  The real downside is that it's only available in the enterprise editions (including [Oasis](https://cloud.arangodb.com/home)).

JSON export is the "thrifty" backup option - I would forget about [arangorestore](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangorestore.html) (it does horrible things to your _id/_key values, and takes forever to do so).  The good news about JSON export is that it's ***EXTREMELY*** portable.  Almost ANY code-base (and even most good DB's) can work with it, so you're never locked into a single product or workflow, or even a specific version of ArangoDB (making up/down-grades much easier).